# game of life in C, how to write in file?

Tags: c

So i have implemented the game of life and now have to put every new generated field into a gif or pbm and at the end with a command I create an animated gif.

The below function is given but I don't get the first parameter, a pointer const char? I see in the function that is the filename, but how do I write that, I'm really confused.

```
static int write_pbm_file(const char *fn, struct game_field *gf) {
int i, j;
FILE *fp;


fp = fopen(fn, "w+");
if(!fp){
    printf("unable to open '%s' - '%s'\n", fn, strerror(errno));

    return -1;
}

fprintf(fp, "P1\n");
fprintf(fp, "%c\n", gf->length);
fprintf(fp, "%c\n", gf->length);

for(i = 0; i < gf->length; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < gf->length; j++)
        fprintf(fp, "%c\n", gf->field[i][j] == 0 ? 48 : 
        gf->field[i][j] == 1 ? 219 : 197);

fclose(fp);

return 0; 
}
```

That's the code where I get to the above function:

```
while( iterations > 0 ) {
    write_pbm_file(..., pstField);
    pstField = game_iteration(pstField);
    iterations--;
}
```

What should I write to create this files? Please help

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer to non-changing character data can most easily be produced by just using a string literal:

```
write_pbm_file("life.pbm", pstField);
```

You probably want to change the filename for each iteration, though. Maybe something like this:

```
char filename[100];

while(...)
{
 sprintf(filename, "life-%03d.pbm", iteration);
 write_pbm_file(filename, pstField);
```

This re-uses your `iteration` counter (which counts backwards), so the first file to be written will have the *largest* number. I added 0-padding to three decimal digits, of course I don't know how many iterations you need.

Comment: That solution is just perfect, it creates for every new field a new file and works. I haven't got linux atm, the assignment has given the following to convert in anmiated pbm: 
convert -delay 75 -loop 0 field* game_of_life.gif

Two questions: convert doesn't work under windows 7 x64, is there any other way?
What should I take instead of field*? May I have 10 files called file-NUM.pbm and what should I write for this command now?

THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: convert is part of ImageMagick: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#windows instead of field* try file-*.pbm

Comment: hm it works fine, the gif gets created but it's not animated. The pbm files are all different but the gif is static, there is no animation hmmm.. Sry for my skills, I'm a beginner^^

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `fn` is simply a path to a file. On a unix system you might write `"/home/someuser/somefile.ext"`, on windows you'd write `"C:\\Some\\Path\\somefile.ext"`

You could also make it configurable through the program arguments, using `argv[1]` or the like. E.g:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc < 1) exit(1);
    char* filename = argv[1];

    ...
    while( iterations > 0 ) {
        write_pbm_file(filename, pstField);
        pstField = game_iteration(pstField);
        iterations--;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the main function I have already arguments inuse for length, iterations and factor. But i know now what's the idea thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `game_field field`, writing it out to, say, `/home/you/foo.pbm` would be

```
write_pbm_file("/home/you/foo.pbm", &field);
```

`const char *` is a type that string literals, `char *`, `const char []` and `char []` decay to.